# generalization of a chaining operator

Tags: r, chaining

I know that the %>% operator allows one to input the LHS to the *first* argument of the RHS, (so that xxx %>% fun() is equivalent to fun(xxx,)) which allows us to "chain" functions together, but is there a way to generalize this operation so that I can pass the LHS to the "nth" argument of the RHS? I am using the R programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `.` to pass the LHS into the desired named argument on right.  If you want to replace 'hey' with 'ho' in 'hey ho' using `gsub(pattern,replacement,text)` then you could do any of the following. Note, `%>%` does not pass the LHS into the first argument of the function, but the first unnamed argument (see the third example below).

```
'hey ho' %>% gsub('hey','ho',.)
'hey ho' %>% gsub('hey','ho',text=.)
'hey ho' %>% gsub(pattern='hey',replacement='ho')
```